# How to redirect from landing page to the home page?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have made a `landingpage.html` and `index.html`, but how do I open a home page from the landing page. The issue I am suffering is, I make the code as and I have troubles how to use it. Is there any simple ans short code for redirecting pages?

```
function redirect_index{
  $("#fold").toggle("fold");
  setTimeout("redirect_index2()", 600);
}

function redirect_index2(){
  document.location_href = "index.html";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#enter_here").click(function(){
    $("#fold").toggle("fold", {}, 1000);
    setTimeout("redirect_index2()", 700);
  });
});
```

Comment: Is the page live on the web so that we can take a look?  Sometimes its just easier to visually see the problem, if you are trying to link from one page to another.

Comment: Oh my... So many syntax errors. D:

Comment: Just one more time, so people are sure "How to redirect from the landing page to the home page?"

Comment: God bless you, Bojangles.

Comment: oops i am aplogized from the wrong question. Here #enter_here is a div, when i clicked it, then the hidden div named #fold rotating from left hand side to the center of the browser and after one sec, the page going to redirect to the other page named index.html. i will gather code tomorrow but this time if you understand this problem please answer me or i will tell you the code on jsfiddle. Thank all of you to reply me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `redirect_index` is not declared properly: `function redirect_index{` should be `function redirect_index(){`, and there are many syntax error with your code - check it with JSLint for errors, and fix them.

For example: `setTimeout("redirect_index2()", 600);` and `setTimeout("redirect_index2()", 700);` are not valid, and so is `$("#fold").toggle("fold", {}, 1000);`.

And what is the point of having two different functions calling the same `redirect_index2()` function? You should stick to the latter, the one wrapped in the document ready function. You will have to wait for everything in the DOM to be loaded first, then fire the animoation and redirection script.

Comment: Not to mention, no such thing as `document.location_href`, and passing `"fold"` as an argument to `toggle()`.

Comment: @Jacedc Oh yes, that too. Basically OP has to check the syntax and the console first, before asking for help. That would expedite the solving a lot.